# NHibernate CreateSQLQuery return list of objects with populated properties (i.e. eager loading)

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am using Nhibernate in a c# application.

I am loading a list of objects from the database using 'CreateSQLQuery'.
The problem is that I also want one of the properties of that object to be populated at the same time.

e.g.
Given objects:
Company
Employee

I have an SQL query looking something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT {e.*}, {c.*}
FROM Employee e
INNER JOIN Company c on e.company = c.id
```

(The actual query has a lot more complexity which is why I can't just use the criteria API or linq.)

My code is then something like this:

```
ISQLQuery sql = session.CreateSQLQuery(sqlText);
sql.AddEntity(e", typeof(Employee));
sql.AddJoin("c",  "e.Company");
sql.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
dbEmlpoyees = sql.List<Employee>().ToList();
```

However, this appears to return a flattened list (i.e. both Employee and Company objects are returned).
I only want the Exployee objects returned but I want the Company property of Employee to be populated. Is this possible in one db call?

(I could just get the list of employees and then populate the Company property for each record while the session is still open but this seems very inefficient)

Comment: You get an error from that code in `sql.List<Employee>()`?

Comment: Yes, because some of the elements in the result set are Company objects.

Comment: But the Employee.Company property is set to the company?

Comment: Short answer is; you can't eager load collections when using a transformer and createSQLQuery this way. Now I have never tried this with NH but look here, http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-load esp. at the bottom couple of queries.

Comment: Why do you use a `DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer`? This query can't return one `Employee` multiple times. Or do you also join some collections in the query? If so, you should expand your question to include that fact.

Answer (score 0):

you can query the two tables individually in one round trip and let the session combine them

```
session.Query<Company>().Where(...).ToFuture();
var results = session.Query<Employee>().Where(...).ToFuture();

return results.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. Although I'm aware of future queries, I hadn't thought of using them for this. Unfortunteley, as the question states, I can't use linq queries or the cirteria api. the solution needs to work with CreateSQLQuery

Comment: just adapt it for SqlQuery and try it.